# How to update data on an iOS app when the app is killed by user?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to create an iOS messaging app, but the problem now is if the app is terminated, I won't be able to do any update on the app whenever a push notification arrives. What I want to achieve is for the app to be able to do all updates (badges, texts) locally.
I understand that I can use PushKit for this, but I'll have to implement VOIP functionality to use it. This app is not a VOIP app.

I've tried to see other apps that don't use VOIP (based on my observation), I found Palringo and GroupMe. It seems to me that the app do a re-sync whenever the app moves from background/terminated to foreground.

My question is, is syncing with the server the only way to have the app updated? If so, how is the data compared between app and server for it to do a sync? What kind of data is kept in the server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should be able to use remote notification -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: you might want to take a look at Notification service extension. This extension will launch itself when you receive push notification even if the app is killed. You won't be able to share app the data from your app to this extension, only what you store in Group User Defaults.

Comment: thanks! i've tested on that, and remote notification only works if the app is in foreground or background, but not when the app is killed. Perhaps I should edit the title,

Comment: @rv7284, thanks! will take a look on that

Comment: You can start updating your data in the background when your app comes to foreground what is problem in that ?

Comment: @vivekDas, I want to update it as the apns notification comes in (together with the data), not by doing a sync and grabbing the data from the server.

Comment: If user has terminated your app forcefully from app switcher, you can't do anything. The only solution in that case is when your app comes to foreground you have to do your task.